# How to embed instagram videos without extra divs and html

Tags: html, css, instagram

I'm building a simple static website that plays videos. I want some of my content to come from Instagram, but when I embed blockquotes from Instagram I get the entire post-- is there a way to only get the video? I am obviously going to credit creators and Instagram, but I would like to be able to format it to match my website.

Here's an example:

```
<blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-permalink="https://www.instagram.com/p/CUSwegHpSXB/?utm_source=ig_embed&amp;utm_campaign=loading" data-instgrm-version="13"></blockquote>
<script async src="https://www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You should to use the instagram API for normal getting a data.

Go to google, you can start from this link..
https://dev.to/hoangit/tutorial-use-instagram-basic-display-api-with-javascript-2j0f

Answer (score -1):

Try this video tag instead

```
<video src="https://www.instagram.com/p/CUSwegHpSXB/?utm_source=ig_embed&amp;utm_campaign=loading"
class="instagram-media"></video>
<script async src="https://www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>
```